# Nondeterministic Turing Machine for $L^*$

Tags: turing-machines, automata, nondeterminism

If $T$ is a Turing Machine that accept a language $L$, I want to define a Turing Machine $T'$ such that accepts the language $L^*$.

An approach:

- $T'$ is a nondeterministic Turing Machine which has many tapes.
- $T'$ 'copies' in a nondeterministic way a prefix from the original string to another tape and then it is applied $T$

So well, what I should know is:

1. How many tapes has $T'$ ?
2. What happens next if $T$ accept this prefix
3. How is this prefix selected?
4. What is the end condition to accept a string in $L^*$.

Comment: Could you write a program for recognizing $L*$ in your favorite programming language, if you had a subroutine for recognizing $L$?

Comment: @D.W. I'm pretty sure that I am

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question to describe how you'd do that, then figure out how to implement that in a Turing machine only after you've done that.  A Turing machine is just a clumsy programming language.